# Meteor Publishing partial collection

Tags: meteor

I want to publish a collection to the user that the user 'owns'

```
Meteor.publish('test', function(){ return questiondummy.find({'author':'Jaspermid'});
});
```

And the subscribe to it with

```
Meteor.subscribe("test");
```

Unfortunately this does not work. I can find the collection within mongodb database with the exact username

```
{ "questionnumber" : 10, "user" : "Jaspermid", "timestamp" : 1407063133137, "answerarray" : [  "1",  "2",  "3",  "4" ], "_id" : "fDcfnenhNsZNAmsze" }
```

**1. Does anyone know why I cannot see this collection on the client side 
2. How and where to incorporate (Meteor.user().username to publish to the current user only?**

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have access to the current user's `_id` from within the publish function through `this.userId`. You can use that to find the username.

http://docs.meteor.com/#publish_userId

```
Meteor.publish('test', function(){
  var user =  Meteor.users.findOne(this.userId);

  if (user)
    return questiondummy.find({user: user.username});

  this.ready();
});
```

`this.ready()` tells the client that the subscription is ready even though you haven't sent any data (as in when the user is not logged in).

Answer (score 0):

1. The selector to `find` should be `{'user':'Jaspermid'}`, and not `{'author':'Jaspermid'}`.
2. Instead of the selector `{'user':'Jaspermid'}`, use `{'user': Meteor.user().username}`

**EDIT**

Oups, `Meteor.user()` can be used "*Anywhere but publish functions*". My mistake.